# how can i add firebase multifactor sms authentication factor

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using this package -> https://github.com/appwise-labs/PhoneVerificationController,
I want to use firebase's secondary authentication function, but I don't know how to modify the code. Can you give me some pointers? Thank you very much.

This is the original code, how can I modify it

```
@IBAction func startVerification() {
        let configuration = Configuration(requestCode: { phone, completion in
            PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phone, uiDelegate: nil, completion: completion)
        }, signIn: { verificationID, verificationCode, completion in
            let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: verificationCode)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { _, error in completion(error) }
        })
        let vc = PhoneVerificationController(configuration: configuration)
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This is the example given by firebase, I am a novice and ask the teacher to teach

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    user?.multiFactor.getSessionWithCompletion({ (session, error) in
      // Send SMS verification code.
      PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,
        uiDelegate: nil,
        multiFactorSession: session) { (verificationId, error) in
          // verificationId will be needed for enrollment completion.
          // Ask user for the verification code.
          let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
            withVerificationID: verificationId!,
            verificationCode: kPhoneSecondFactorVerificationCode)
          let assertion = PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(with: credential)
          // Complete enrollment. This will update the underlying tokens
          // and trigger ID token change listener.
          user.multiFactor.enroll(with: assertion, displayName: displayName) { (error) in
            // ...
          }
      }
    })
```

I modified it like this, the red warning (Missing argument for parameter 'signIn' in call),

```
   let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
            user?.multiFactor.getSessionWithCompletion({ (session, error) in
        let configuration = Configuration(requestCode: { phone, completion in
            PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phone, uiDelegate: nil, multiFactorSession: session) { (verificationId, error) in
                let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
                  withVerificationID: verificationId!,
                  verificationCode: kPhoneSecondFactorVerificationCode)
                let assertion = PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(with: credential)
                // Complete enrollment. This will update the underlying tokens
                // and trigger ID token change listener.
                user.multiFactor.enroll(with: assertion, displayName: displayName) { (error) in
                }
            
            }
                                    
        
        })
        
        
        let vc = PhoneVerificationController(configuration: configuration)
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

where do i need to fix

Comment: The code and question are a little vague. Are you asking how to modify a third party library to perform some function or are you asking how to use Phone Authentication in Firebase?

Comment: I'm using firebase two factor authentication (login after mail + 2nd level phone verification)